# Resharper suddenly gone from Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have Resharper 8.2 installed on my computer. I didn't shut down the computer from yesterday and Visual studio 2013 was kept open.
Yesterday, I had Resharper working fine and today, it's gone. I don't have the menu "Resharper" on the top and I don't have the tool at all.

So be it. I reinstalled Resharper from the exe file. Nothing.
I deleted Resharper, cleaned all the files and installed it once more. Nothing in VS 2013.

I also have Visual Studio 2010 and Resharper is here (I have the menu and the tools).

Am I the only one experiencing this "feature"? Does anyone know how to solve this?

I don't know what to try.

Comment: The first thing to try would be contacting tech support of resharper, and see what they have to say about it. If anyone has heard about this problem, it's going to be them.

Comment: Can you find Resharper in "Tools" -> "Extensions and Updates"?

Comment: I bought an update. I no longer have this version...

Comment: This happens to me constantly! Every now and then, my Visual Studio 2015 freezes and when I end it via Task Manager and reopen VS, Resharper is completely gone! I normally go ahead and reinstall Resharper and all is good again.